# How to set everyone in a certain area, except myself, in adventure mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to set up a command that sets everyone in a 27 by 27 square into adventure mode with the exception of myself.

`/gamemode adventure @a[name=!JP2K],[distance=..27,]`

This didn't work, and even if it did, the distance command is only a radius, so that doesn't help much either.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Combining two questions into one does not make that one not a duplicate. This question is [put everyone except me in adventure mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239747/in-minecraft-how-to-make-everyone-in-gamemode-1-except-yourself-gamemode-2?rq=1) plus [make an "adventure mode boundary"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229652/is-there-a-way-to-set-an-adventure-mode-boundary-in-minecraft) and should be closed as a duplicate of both quetsions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set an "Adventure Mode Boundary" in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229652/is-there-a-way-to-set-an-adventure-mode-boundary-in-minecraft)

Comment: I disagree: the solution here is a combination of the two, and neither of the two proposed dupe targets really go into how to put them together.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a command that might work.

```
/gamemode adventure @a[x=1,y=2,z=3,dx=4,dy=5,dz=6,name=!JP2K]
```

Replace 1,2,3 with the x,y,z of the search center. Basically where you want to start with the search radius which is 4,5,6. Replace 4 with how far out on the X axis you want to go. Replace 5 with how far out on the Y axis you want to go. Replace 6 with how far out on the X axis you want to go. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

No brackets around the comma and no comma before the closing bracket:

```
/gamemode adventure @a[name=!JP2K,distance=..27]
```

I recommend looking up a commands tutorial or at least example commands instead of guessing the syntax.

Comment: i thought the distance command is a radius and not an area?

Comment: /gamemode adventure @a[name=!JP2K,distance=..27] this is the correct syntax i believe. but it is still a radius command not an area command

Comment: `name=!JP2K`, not `nameR!JP2K`

Comment: @pppery Thanks. I didn't press the button long enough on my phone keyboard. There was also a `[` instead of the second `=`, that's fixed now as well.

Answer (score -2):

/gamemode adventure @a[name=!JP2k, distance=..27]

Comment: the issue with this is that ``distance`` indicates a circular area, not a square area. you'd need to use the ``x= y= z= dx= dy= dz=`` method instead.